# Cuckoo Hashing Collisions lead to overflow

Tags: java, algorithm, hash, stack-overflow, collision

I'm trying to implement cuckoo hashing with hash functions:
hash1: key.hashcode() % capacity
hash2: key.hashcode() / capacity % capacity

With an infinite loop check and rehashing method doubling capacity. The program works fine with small amount of data, but when data gets big (around 20k elements) the program keeps getting rehashing until the capacity gets overflowed.

I figured that mostly the infinite rehashing causes by the data with exactly same hashcode. After rehashing, there will be chance other data get same hashcode and causing rehashing again.

I already use Java built-in hashcode but the chance of same hashcodes still high when data is large. Even I modified a little bit hashcode method, eventually there is still data with same hashcode.

So which hash method should I use to prevent this?

Comment: Are you sure your data elements are unique?

Comment: They're not unique, but I'm sure existed elements get handled without being inserted.
Also, I already checked by printing out data (type String in this case). The issue causing by different String but have same hashcode.

Comment: Ok, in that case, use a custom hash function. What can be your `capacity`?

Comment: I made a custom one, then it still also get same problem because eventually another group of data get same hashcode using myHashCode function.

I even tried to combining my and built-in hashcode. Still not working.

My capacity could be any. I let it grow each rehashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A usual method to create a hash function is generally to use primes. I write a function (below), with which, I don't guarantee no collisions, but it should be lessened.

```
hashFunction1(String s){
    int k = 7;         //take a prime number, can be anything (I just chose 7)
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        k *= (23 * (int)(s.charAt(i)));
        k %= capacity;
    }
}
//23 is another randomly chosen number.
```

You can write a similar hash function as hashFunction2, choosing two different prime numbers. But here, the main problem is, for strings "stop" and "pots", this gives same hash code.

So, an improvization over this function can be:

```
hashFunction1(String s){
    int k = 7;         //take a prime number, can be anything (I just chose 7)
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        k *= (23 * (int)(s.charAt(i)));
        k += (int)(s.charAt(i));
        k %= capacity;
    }
}
```

which will resolve this (for most cases, if not all).

If you still find this function bad, instead of s.charAt(i), you can use a unique prime number mapped to every character, ie. a=3, b=5, c=7, d=11 and so on. This should resolve collision even more.

EDIT:

1. You are using `+n`, which is a constant.
2. `2` is not the prime to be used in such cases. Use an odd prime number, 3 works.

Comment: This is a bit similar to my custom function.

I used prime number of 2.

And for each character, I increase the prime


n = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
   k += ((int)s.charAt(i) + n ) * n;
   n++;
}

But I still get the same problem.

Comment: Not similar, there are issues with yours. I'll edit my answer and specify those issues, in the meantime, please use my hashFunction and use primes (7,23) for 1st and (13,31) for second.

Comment: Nice !! It seems working well now. But how do you deal with rehashing? My rehash method simply double the capacity. It runs fine, but the capacity keeps getting really large although the load factor is still pretty small (About 10%).

Comment: @concuagia, the usual implementation of cuckoo hash doubles the capacity, but I don't know if that is necessary everytime. You can increase the capacity ~10% and then see what happens. Also, in the wiki page of cuckoo hashing, it quotes: "There is no need to allocate new tables for the rehashing: We may simply run through the tables to delete and perform the usual insertion procedure on all keys found not to be at their intended position in the table."

Comment: I've read and tried that. Doesn't work very well, I'll try to make it better then. About the capacity, I tried increase less than double and it simply took more time to run but still got really big capacity.